# Replace specific rows with their sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am having the dataframe (*df_plot_country*) https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlPw3RIiTz1ChRhXIMrQ0f9r6-kx?e=6LOug9
same on the picture [See pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JTp6.png) containing 177 rows. I would like to have the top 10 countries by 'total_bookings' along with a new row 'others' containing the sums of the rest columns.
So far I was able to extract the Top 10 [see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjMLJ.png) with :

```
df_plot_country_sorted = df_plot_country.sort_values(['total_bookings'], ascending=False, ignore_index=True)[:10]
```

How should I add one more row named "Others" which will sum the values for the rest 166 countries ?

Comment: please post data in place of images

Comment: Please post the data here, not images. (Image links are ephemeral, they break or die, they're offsite and they can't be indexed/viewed inline).

Comment: Please make sure to tag pandas questions [tag:pandas], they get answered faster. This one wasn't about [tag:matplotlib] or [tag:jupyter-notebook].

Comment: Thank you for your advice  @smci. I did add the df as link to csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following syntax to sum each column and row in Pandas DataFrame:

**Sum each column:**

```
df.sum(axis=0)
```

**Sum each row:**

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

```
# Set country column to index
df_plot_country_sorted.set_index("country", inplace=True)

#Total sum per column: 
df_plot_country_sorted.loc['Others',:] = df_plot_country_sorted.sum(axis=0)
```

Later you can reset the index

```
# add inplace=True
df_plot_country_sorted.reset_index()
```